# Tkinter How to remove title bar of window, but save program's icon in a taskbar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm creating program with my own title bar, so how can I remove title bar of window, but save program's icon in a taskbar? I'm using `root.overrideredirect(1)` in my code, I partially solved the problem, when the window minimized, I process this event and at this point do

```
root.withdraw()
root.overrideredirect(False)
root.iconify()
```

but I don't know what to do when the window is maximized.